# What happened to my chat room?

Tags: support, chat

Some time ago, I created a chatroom for the Reflections language. Now, I can't find it, and if I click [the link on the Reflections page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74079/reflections), it's not found. Has it been deleted? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, inactive rooms get deleted automatically after a while:

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. **A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.**
>
> — Source: [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention)

I've undeleted the room for you. If you can get a bit more activity in there, you shouldn't have to worry about it being deleted again. However, inactive rooms will still *freeze* after 14 days of inactivity, which will prevent further messages. Should that happen and you need the room again, feel free to ping one us moderators in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) and we'll unfreeze it for you.